# Sftp not able to connect in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, ftp

I am not able to connect to Sftp in magento2.2.5

Here is my code:

```
public function execute()
    {
        $connection = $this->sftp->open(
                    array(
                        'host' => 'myhostname',
                        'username' => 'myusername',
                        'password' => 'mypassword',
                        'port' =>22,
                        'passive' => true
                    )
                );
        if($connection){
        echo "true";

        }else{
            echo "false";
        }
                //print_r($connection);
        die;
```

But it is returning false.

I don't know what is the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: remove if and else and check by var_dump($this->sftp->ls());

Comment: The connection is being listed.. But the connection is failed.

Comment: Are you working on cloud magento ?

Comment: Yes, I am working on cloud..

Answer (score 1):

In Magento, *$this->sftp->open();* returns null.
you can php function is_null() function in the condition.

```
public function execute()
    {
        $connection = $this->sftp->open(
                    array(
                        'host' => 'myhostname',
                        'username' => 'myusername',
                        'password' => 'mypassword',
                        'port' =>22,
                        'passive' => true
                    )
                );
        if(is_null($connection)){
        echo "true";
         //Here your code.....

        }else{
            echo "false";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly install PHP ssh2 extension and then use the following code.

If you get not connected double check `your IP is whitelisted or not`

```
$strServer = '*******';
$strServerPort = '*******';
$strServerUsername = '*******';
$strServerPassword = '*******';

//connect to server
$resConnection = ssh2_connect($strServer, $strServerPort);

if(ssh2_auth_password($resConnection, $strServerUsername, $strServerPassword))
{
     //Initialize SFTP subsystem            
     echo "connected";
}
else
{
      echo "not connected";
}
```

It works for me.